# I am writing DICE (climate) objective function

Tags: julia, julia-jump

The code below tries to build an objective for DICE climate model.

Where is the mistake in objective code? Please suggest change in objective fn

```
t = range(1,stop=100) # Time period
tstep = 5 #   Years per Period 
@variable(dice_model,  C[t] >= 0); # Consumption (trillions 2005 US dollars per year)
elasmu = 1.45 # Elasticity of marginal utility of consumption  
prstp = 0.015 #  Initial rate of social time preference per year 
#  rr(τ): utility time preference discount 
rr(τ) = 1/((1+prstp)^(tstep*(τ-1)))
@objective (dice_model, max,sum((C[t]^(1-elasmu) / (1-elasmu)) * l * rr(τ)) for i in t)
```

Comment: Are you aware of this? https://github.com/olugovoy/climatedice
There is no constraints in your code, and for nonlinear models the functions you call in your objective or constraint functions need to be "registered"

Comment: I believe `τ` is not defined here, neither `l`

Answer (score 0):

- Please provide a reproducible example.
- It should be `Max`, not `max`
- You're summing over `i` but `i` does not appear in the expression
- I assume you meant `C[i]`